# What is this View or Widget called? Floating hint/note Android

Tags: android

I have been quite amused with this Floating kind of note in Whatsapp and I want to use it in my application for EditText password fields to notify user about valid password requirements

Is this some ready to use widget or will I have to write one myself?

I can't find any help related to this.

(Maybe my Google search skills are weak)

Image:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vbY6.png

(P.s. I can't post images directly because I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the setError() method of the EditText.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Thanks, I should have searched enough or atleast have read the docs properly